# Compile existing require.js project with any ecma6 transpiler into a single working file

Tags: javascript, requirejs, ecmascript-6, babeljs, traceur

We have an existing ecma5 javascript project that heavily uses require. In production we compile it all into a single file using require's r.js. We want to start transitioning to ecma6, and our first hurdle has been to get the existing code to be compiled into a single file and work.

I've made a simple project that puts some text in the body. Here is the github (short setup instructions can be found there):

https://github.com/cjbrass/ecma6-test

dev.html uses the src files, and works just fine. live.html uses the built files, and we cannot seem to get that to work. The fabric compile task runs, and generates the appropriate files, but the javascript does not work.

We are currently using traceur, and have tried out babel, but have no particular attachment to either. We just want to get this working with any ecma6 transpiler.

I was not able to find any good examples to base our work off of, so we feel like we are flying in the dark, and need some direction.

Comment: Did you look at jspm? Also, es2015 is a superset. You can always transpile to es5 and keep require calls or anything you like. Then it's just another build step.

Comment: Have not looked at jspm, I'll give it a google.

Comment: I think, you should try [webpack](https://webpack.github.io/). It supports AMD, so you won't have to rewrite your old RequireJS code. And it has a [babel-loader](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader), so it'll be pretty easy to start writing new ES6 code.